# How to change AWS sticky sessions cookie name for Load Balancer to a custom name

Tags: amazon-web-services, session, aws-application-load-balancer, sticky-session

Is there any way to change AWS sticky sessions cookie name for Load Balancer to a custom name? For example AWSALB -> MY_AWSALB.

[image]

I know about `Application-controlled session stickiness` where I can use application cookies, but I need to use exactly `Duration-based session stickiness` with my custom name.

[Sticky sessions for your Application Load Balancer](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html)

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Sadly no, you can't change it. You can only customize [Application-based stickiness](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/sticky-sessions.html#application-based-stickiness) cookie.